# Application hangs when I do join for PipelinedRDD and RDD from DStream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, flume-ng

I use spark 1.6.0 with Spark Streaming and have one problem with wide operations.

Code example:
There is RDD called "a" which has type: class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'.

"a" was received as:

```
# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
    lines = sc.textFile(filename)
    parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
    clients = parts.map(lambda p: Row(client_id=int(p[0]), clientname=p[1] ...))

    # Infer the schema, and register the DataFrame as a table.
    schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(clients)
    schemaPeople.registerTempTable("clients")

    client_list = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM clients")
```

and after:

```
a = client_list.map(lambda entry: (int(entry[1]), value_from_entry(entry)))
```

There is second part "b" with type class 'pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream'.
I am receiving "b" from Flume:

```
DStreamB = flumeStream.map(lambda tup: function_for_map(tup[1].encode('ascii','ignore')))
```

and

```
b = DStreamB.map(lambda event: (int(event[2]), value_from_event(event)))
```

**Problem is:** When i try join as:

```
mult = b.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(a))
```

**my application hangs in this stage** (Now I show the screen after b.pprint() and before stage .join())

[image]

But when I am adding:

1. Declare RDD "test":

   ```
   test = sc.parallelize(range(1, 100000)).map(lambda k: (k, 'value'))
   ```

   and do:

   ```
   mult0 = a.join(test)
   mult = b.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(mult0))`
   ```

   Then it works(!!):

   [image: screen 2]
2. Also I can do:

   ```
   mult0 = b.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(test))
   ```

**Thus:**

I have RDDs "a" and "test". DStream "b".
And I can multiply:

- a * test * b
- b * test

But I cannot do 'b * a'.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the advice of user6910411 I did caching "a" as

```
a = client_list.map(lambda entry: (int(entry[1]), value_from_entry(entry))).cache()
```

and problem was resolved.